# Deploying C# application with UAC

Tags: c#, .net, c++, deployment, uac

We are creating a C# .net application, which uses a .dll file developed in
C++. It also requires some user controls developed by a third party
(bundled as .dll with the application.) If we run this application on
a machine with UAC enabled, it executes as expected. However, if we
deploy it using an installer created through Visual Studio Deployment
project, it crashes. If the installed executable is "Run as
administrator" it works.
Also, if a manifest requiring administrator privilleges is added to
the C# executable it runs fine after installation, however UAC asks
for permission everytime the exectable is run.
Is there something which can be specified to always run as admin
without having the UAC popup everytime or the installer changed such
that it does not require admin privilleges to run after installation
(since the application if run without installation does not need admin
privilleges) ?

Comment: You cannot stop UAC popping up if you are running as admin and UAC is turned on, as this would defeat the purpose of UAC.

Comment: I agree that it should not be the case, however what I meant was if given permission once then is there a way of making it remember that it is a trustable executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you cannot run as administrator without the UAC prompt. That would make life too easy for malware writers.

I suspect the location where it's installed matters. Usually that's under \Program Files\, and that's also its default working directory. However, the program may not write there when ran under a non-admin account. Is it possible the DLL tries to write to the current working directory?

Comment: I think this resolved it. Once I removed the logging to a file the application didn't crash and now works normally. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a solution. Deport your code which require elevation to a windows service. You app then can make calls to you service to run elevated commands (usingWCF, RPC, remoting or anything you want).

But you have to be careful :

- **it can be a security hole because a non elevated program can potentially ask an elevated one to do the job**. If you app contains bugs or not enough data check, it can be dangerous.
- your service will always run
- your service will run with a specific user identity, or a builtin. The process won't get the identity of the logged user. I think delegation won't work without UAC.

Comment: the program as such doesnt need admin access as such, its only after isntallation that this problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

As answered already, there is no way around the UAC prompt during app startup if admin rights are requested in the app's manifest.

You might use a workaround, though: during installation, set write permissions for everyone on the log file or folder.

Please note that is not a "clean" solution. Instead you should change the DLL's code to log someplace else.